# azure data factory - set variable to prior business date

Tags: azure-pipelines, azure-data-factory

I have a ADF pipeline.  I'd like to feed it a variable with the prior business date.  Right now I added a SET VARIABLE, which I am able to grab the current date using..

```
@formatDateTime(utcNow(),'yyyy-MM-dd')
```

Now to get the prior date I have to check today's 'DAY', if its sunday I need to subtract 2 days from date, if its Monday I need to subtract 3 days from date.

How can I add this logic to set variable?  I know I can create an azure function to create the date but that seems very excessing for something so simple.

thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use IF expression to validate which day it is via dayofweek function

Identify which day :
@string(dayOfWeek(formatDateTime(utcNow(),'yyyy-MM-dd')))

If 0 then Sunday if 1 Monday

Then use  adddays function to substract the days

Comment: thanks. can you help me with syntax of it then or case.  i get different errors no matter what i try.@if(
    'test'=='test', 'yes','no'
)

Comment: also doesn't work... @if(
    equals('yes','yes'),'boom'
)

Comment: hold on... I think i got it... I'll come right back

Comment: thank you!  it works now... @if(
    equals(dayOfWeek(utcNow()),7),
    formatDateTime(addDays(utcNow(),-2),'yyyy-MM-dd'),
    if(equals(dayOfWeek(utcNow()),1),
    formatDateTime(addDays(utcNow(),-3),'yyyy-MM-dd'),
    formatDateTime(addDays(utcNow(),-1),'yyyy-MM-dd')
    )
)